# Create a trigger to run a long time executed function C#

Tags: c#, azure, http, triggers, azure-functions

I have a function that supposes to run every night at 12 AM and to do some job
usually it takes 2 hours...

I want to create a trigger that calls it.
so I created an Azure function app with time trigger that calls with HTTP request to my controller that calls my function.

the controller function I created just for test.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<bool> updateFromRegAdmin() 
    {
        try
        {

           RegEditApi_Service.retrieveRegAdminApiCredentials();



            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.writeToLog(Logger.LOG_SEVERITY_TYPE.Error, "", "updateFromRegAdmin ", e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

so as I said the function "retrieveRegAdminApiCredentials" runs 2 hours.
and the problem is the request comes to timeout after a few minutes...

so how can I create a request that just triggers the inner function and let it run in the background?

by the way, I can't create a trigger on the server without an HTTP request because my company has scaled servers on Azure(it will run my trigger multiple time and create DB duplicates).

my previous solution to that was...

```
 public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<GetExchangeRates>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(00, 00))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);


    }

} 

public class GetExchangeRates : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
       Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(100000, 900000);

        Thread.Sleep(randomNumber);

        RegEditApi_Service.retrieveRegAdminApiCredentials();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you have is an Azure Function Timer trigger, that sends an HTTP request to your server with "RegEditApi_Service.retrieveRegAdminApiCredentials()".

The problem is, your function times out. To solve this, you should have the HTTP endpoint behind "retrieveRegAdminApiCredentials()", return immediately on accepting the request.

If you need some return value from the server, you should have the server put a message on some queue ( like Azure Storage queue) and have another Azure Function that listens to this queue, and accepts the message.

If the result of the long operation is relatively small, you can just have the result in the message. Otherwise, you would need to perform some operation, but this operation should be much quicker, because you have already performed the long running operation, and kept the answer, so now you will just retrieve it, and possibly do some cleanup.

You can also look into Azure Durable Functions, it is intended for this use case, but is still in preview, and I'm not sure how much benefit it will give you :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-3-async-http-apis

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't need the response, I just need it to call the function "retrieveRegAdminApiCredentials"
can you give me an example how to implement that please?

Comment: Then you just need to make the HTTP call non-blocking somehow and allow the azure function to run to completion. How to do this depends on how you make the HTTP call, you can google for "fire and forget LibraryName". This is considered a bad practice though, because you won't have any feedback on if the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a dedicated component able to schedule and execute a queue of tasks. There are nice frameworks for that, but if you dislike those for whatever reason, then make sure you initiate/reuse idle thread and force long execution there. As such, your API will return something alike: 200, OK meaning that process has started successfuly.

Key idea: distinct your threads explicitly. That's actually quite challenging.

Comment: Can you please give an example usage of that?

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions by default run to a maximum of 15 minutes (maybe 5, too lazy to check the documentation right now :-) ).

If your function is on a Consumption Plan, you can't increase this time.  You can do it if you host your function on a App Service plan.

Comment: 5 minutes by default, 10 minutes max if configured in `host.json`

Comment: good to know that!
but the problem occurs on a simple HTTP request from client